# Leg hurts during side star plank

Tags: planks

I am trying to achieve a side star elbow plank. I am quite adept at the regular elbow plank (5 mins) and side planks (1.5 minutes). However, I can not even hold a side star plank for 10 seconds. It is physically almost impossible to keep my leg up in the air. Rather quickly I get pain on the side of my leg and the lower part of the glutes (perhaps *gluteus maximus* or *obturator interanus*) that makes it difficult to do.

I have strengthened those muscles a lot with high resistance biking and squats.

What is going on that is making it difficult for me to do a side star plank? Is this normal? How can I strengthen my leg so it can do this better?

Comment: How high are you bringing your leg? As I understand it, you initially start by only lifting it a little, maybe enough to keep it parallel to the ground. It's also important to be able to do it without major tension. If it's a strain to lift your leg to that height, it's probably too much to hold it.